# PHP Accounting for magic quotes

Tags: php

I noticed a block of code similar to the following in the PHP laravel framework:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $magics = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);

    foreach ($magics as &$magic)
    {
        $magic = array_strip_slashes($magic);
    }
}
```

I don't really know how to go about testing this, but if I put this in a start.php file that I include on every page, will it take care of magic quotes so I don't have to worry about them?

Edit:

Here is the array_strip_slashes from laravel:

```
function array_strip_slashes($array)
{
    $result = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $key = stripslashes($key);

        // If the value is an array, we will just recurse back into the
        // function to keep stripping the slashes out of the array,
        // otherwise we will set the stripped value.
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            $result[$key] = array_strip_slashes($value);
        }
        else
        {
            $result[$key] = stripslashes($value);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `array_strip_slashes` shown, but assuming that it works correctly --

Yes, that function should undo the magic-quotes effect.  If magic quotes is *not* turned on, then that code doesn't run at all.

As others will no doubt also point out, it is better to just turn them off.  Alas, in some shared hosting environments, it is difficult to do that.  At best, the code will save you from getting burned.  At worst, it will be a piece of harmless cruft that can be removed at some point in the future when historians look back on magic quotes and laugh at us.

Answer (score 0):

This will "take care" of magic quotes in that it will remove them, which is a good thing.  It would be a lot better to just turn them off (in PHP 5.3 they should be off by default).

Comment: Yes, but just in the case that other people will be using this script.

Comment: @Bethesda they would have to have the `array_strip_slashes` function